# Cargo test not displaying any output and not showing all tests

Tags: testing, rust, rust-cargo

Running `cargo test` does not show all 4 of the tests, and it doesn't show any output of any of the tests I run.
I have 4 tests:

```
test common::tests::test_workingdays 
test documents::tests::create_docs 
test emailer::tests::test_attachments 
test emailer::tests::test_format_attachments
```

```sh
$ cargo test
   Compiling te-pm-analytics v0.1.0 (/home/charlie/thoughtexpress/rust/te-pm-analytics)
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 2.44s
     Running target/debug/deps/main-253a09bf91ed177c

running 4 tests
test common::tests::test_workingdays ... ok
test emailer::tests::test_attachments ... FAILED
error: test failed, to rerun pass '--bin main'
```

It only runs two of them and does not even give me information on what has failed.

Answer (score 5):

So the reason that this is happening, is that of the 4 tests I have

```
test common::tests::test_workingdays 
test documents::tests::create_docs 
test emailer::tests::test_attachments 
test emailer::tests::test_format_attachments
```

both `test_attachments` and `test_format_attachments` were failing, however `test_format_attachments` had a `std::process::exit(1)` condition inside the function it was testing, and therefore it killed the process before the tests were able to return.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, now I have an idea why I'm also experiencing this. Forgot some part of my code where I placed code that executes `std::process::exit(1)` as well.

Comment: I found out what caused my problems. It's not that I have `std::process::exit(1)` in the code. I updated my Postgresql server from 9.x to 14.x. Perhaps in the configuration file of PSQL I overlooked on setting the same values. 

My cargo test result was oddly weird as every time I run `cargo test`, different results come up, so I assumed it has something to do with multithreading. So when I set `cargo test -- --test-threads=1`, the problems immediately disappeared. I'm using Rocket and Diesel and many other crates. I will post about it if someone encounters this problem as well.